# Encontrar numero en cuadricula

Tags: c

Ayuda, necesito resolver este programa,llevo dias pensando y no encuentro ninguna solucion: 
[image: Programa]

Necesito encontrar la celda:

Yo ingresaria numero de filas y columnas y otra variable que sera "p" que sera el numero a encontrar.

```
//Localizacion de la celda

#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int n,m,p,res,fil,col;

    printf("Introduce el nombre de filas: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("Introduce el nombre de columnas: ");
    scanf("%d",&m);
    printf("Escribe el valor de p: ");
    scanf("%d",&p);

    // NO logro avanzar mas
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Aprovechando tus variables a mi se me ocurre algo tal que:

```
int matriz[n][m];

// Rellenas la matriz como creas conveniente

int f,c, ok=0;
for( f = 0; f < n && !ok; f++) {
  for( c = 0; c < m && !ok; c++) {
    if(matriz[f][c] == p)
      ok = 1;
  }
}

if( ok )
  printf("El número se encuentra en las coordenadas (%d,%d)\n",f,c);
else
  printf("No se ha encontrado el número\n");
```

Aunque para el futuro te recomendaría hacer uso de nombres de variables más descriptivos. Mejora la legibilidad del código y ello evita que cometas errores tontos.

Answer (score 1):

- Primero que nada no veo la necesidad incluir la libreria `math.h`, por lo tanto eso lo puedes sacar.
- En segundo lugar declaraste varias variables que no usas, ademas como buena practica de programacion siempre lo mejor es usar identificadores explicativos, es decir, que al leer el nombre de las variables entiendas inmediatamente cual es su funcion, es por esto que usare `filas`, `columnas` y `numero`.
- Por ultimo, como deseas que el numero de filas y columnas sea ingresado en tiempo de ejecucion tendras que usar la funcion `malloc` que se encuentra en la libreria `stdlib.h` para reservar el espacio de memoria que usara tu matriz (y liberarla posteriormente), y tambien tendras que manejar punteros (en el estandar C99 se puede hacer uso de `int arreglo[tamano]` para declarar un arreglo de tamaño variable siendo `tamano` una variable entera, sin embargo a partir del estandar C11 el poder hacer esto no esta asegurado y es algo opcional, por lo que dependera de la decision del que creo el compilador que uses si `int arreglo[tamano]` es valido o no, es por esto que como mencione anteriormente la mejor opcion es usar `malloc`).

Considerando lo anteriormente dicho escribi el siguiente codigo.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
  int **matriz;
  int i, j, filas, columnas, numero;

  printf("Introduce el nombre de filas: ");
  scanf("%d", &filas);

  printf("Introduce el nombre de columnas: ");
  scanf("%d", &columnas);

  printf("Escribe el valor del numero a encontrar: ");
  scanf("%d", &numero);

  matriz = malloc(columnas * sizeof(int *));

  for (i = 0; i < filas; i++)
    matriz[i] = malloc(columnas * sizeof(int));

  for (i = 0; i < filas; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < columnas; j++) {
      printf("Ingrese que numero desea ingresar en la celda [%d, %d]: ", i, j);
      scanf("%d", &matriz[i][j]);
    }

  for (i = 0; i < filas; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < columnas; j++)
      if (matriz[i][j] == numero)
        printf("El numero se encontro en la fila %d y en la columna %d\n", i, j);

  for (i = 0; i < filas; i++)
    free(matriz[i]);

  free(matriz);

  return 0;
}
```

Ante cualquier duda, consulta o critica puedes preguntar sin miedo.

Saludos y suerte!

Comment: De antemano muchas gracias por responder.

Comment: Lo siguiente es que me tira "El numero no se encuentra en la matriz".

Comment: En teoria si tiene 4 filas y 5 columnas y por ejemplo buscamos el 14, deberia de decirnos la fila 2 y columna 4. Este ejemplo de programa me da ami que no lo lograre hacer por mi solo, asi que estara atento a que algun guru lo logre dar con el y despues estudiarlo paso a paso para saber como lo hizo.

Comment: de todas formas muchas gracias @CodigoFasil

Answer (score 0):

No lo probé, como mucho tira error de compilación, pero te debería servir para ver la algoritmia:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {    

    int fil, col, numeroAbuscar;

    printf("Introduce el nombre de filas: ");
    scanf("%d",&fil);
    printf("Introduce el nombre de columnas: ");
    scanf("%d",&col);
    printf("Escribe el valor que quiere buscar: ");
    scanf("%d",&numeroAbuscar);

    int matriz[filas][columnas]; // Declaro la matriz

    // LLENO LA MATRIZ...

    // Busco
    int i, j, ok = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < filas && !ok; i++) { // Mientras no sobrepase la ultima fila y no haya encontrado el numero
        for(j = 0; j < columas && !ok; j++) { // Mientras no sobrepase la ultima columna y no haya encontrado el numero
            if(matriz[i][j] == numeroABuscar)
                ok = 1;
        }
    }

    if(ok)
        printf("El numero fue encontrado en la fila %d y la columna %d\n", i, j);
    else
        printf("El numero no se encuentra en la matriz\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Espero haberte sido de ayuda.

Saludos!

Comment: Gracias por el intento amigo pero no me funciona, te dejo el enunciado,por si te puedes aclarar.

Comment: Un rectángulo está dividida en n filas y m columnas. Las filas están numeradas desde el 0 hasta el n-1 y las columnas desde el 0 hasta el m-1. Se trata de escribir un programa que, dado un número p comprendido entre 0 y nxm-1, nos indique a qué fila y columna pertenece este número. Por ejemplo, si el rectángulo está dividido en n = 4 filas y m = 5 columnas y escribimos p = 14, debe responder: fila 2, columna 4.

Comment: El programa haurà de demanar els valors de n, m i p, tots enters. 

Com a pista direm que si els números de la primera fila els dividim per n (5 en aquest cas) el quocient té part entera igual a 0, és a dir, la fila a la qual pertanyen. I el mateix passa amb totes les files

Comment: Como pista diremos que si los números de la primera fila los dividimos por n (5 en este caso) el cociente tiene parte entera igual a 0, es decir, la fila a la que pertenecen. Y lo mismo ocurre con todas las filas

Comment: Gracias de todas formas por intentarlo se agradece bastante.

Comment: Hola! Por qué dices que no funciona? Acordate de llenar la matriz, podés hacerlo con un doble for al igual de como se recorre

Answer (score 0):

Si las celdas de la matriz están numeradas como la imagen que proporcionaste entonces el numero de fila y columna estarán dados por:

```
    columna = p%col;
    fila = p/col;
```

Espero que te sirva.